# Find position avoiding For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list:

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

And a function `sizeFunc[element_]` which returns the size `{rows,columns}` of the element, for example:

```
In= sizeFunc[c]
Out= {3,3}
```

To be clear, all elements are symbolic. I want to find the first element in the above list whose size is not `{1,1}`. So far I tried:

```
Position[{a,b,c,d,e,f},(sizeFunc[#]=={1,1})&]
```

The above is just an attempt, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for helping.

**With for loop (what I want to avoid):**

```
list={a,b,c,d,e,f};
For[k = 1, k <= Length[list], k++,
 If[sizeFunc[list[[k]]] != {1, 1},
  firstNonScalark = k; Break[];
 ]
];
```

Comment: `=!=` might be useful.

Comment: Do you mean `Dimensions[ ]`?

Comment: @belisarius What do you mean? `Dimensions[]` has nothing to do with it, I have my own function `sizeFunc[]` and I'm searching for the first element from the left whose size is not `{1,1}`

Comment: `LengthWhile[list, sizeFunc[#] == {1,1}&]+1`.  I think `For` is pretty awful in Mathematica and can always be avoided.  If you do need a procedural loop, use `Do` which at least localizes the iterator, and is more compact and more readable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks it works BUT when no element in a list has size other than `{1,1}`, the returned value exceeds list dimensions by 1. How do I bound the value to the length of the list?

Comment: I already gave you something to use along with `Position[]`…

Comment: Evidently I'm not understanding your question. Sorry.

Comment: If I understand your question, I think the condition of the `If` in the `For` loop example you gave to describe the behavior should be `sizeFunc[list[[k]]] != {1,1}`, and not Equal.

Comment: @MarcoB Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll define a `sizeFunc` to play with:

```
Clear[sizeFunc]
sizeFunc[a] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[b] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[c] = {3, 2}; 
sizeFunc[d] = {2, 4}; sizeFunc[e] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[f] = {1, 1};
```

**UPDATE:**

OP mentioned the desired behavior when all elements return {1, 1}. Taking that into consideration, one can define the following function:

```
firstnonscalar[l_List] := Module[
  {position},
  If[(position = First@FirstPosition[l, el_ /; sizeFunc[el] != {1, 1}]) != "NotFound",
   position,
   Length[l]
  ]
 ]
```

As requested, this will return the position of the first element whose `sizeFunc` does not return {1, 1}, or alternatively the `Length` of the list, which is the position of the last element.

---

**Original answer:**

In my understanding of your question, you want the (position of) the first element whose `sizeFunc` is not `{1,1}`.

If you want the element itself, then the following would work:

```
SelectFirst[{a, b, c, d, e}, sizeFunc[#] != {1, 1} &]
(* Out: c *)
```

If you want the position of that element in the list, then the following would work instead:

```
First@FirstPosition[{a, b, c, d, e}, el_ /; sizeFunc[el] != {1, 1}]
(* Out: 3 *)
```

---

Here is what happens to these functions if there are *no elements* for which `sizeFunc` is different from `{1, 1}`:

```
Clear[sizeFunc]
sizeFunc[a] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[b] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[c] = {1, 1}; 
sizeFunc[d] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[e] = {1, 1}; sizeFunc[f] = {1, 1};
SelectFirst[{a, b, c, d, e}, sizeFunc[#] != {1, 1} &]
First@FirstPosition[{a, b, c, d, e}, el_ /; sizeFunc[el] != {1, 1}]

(* Out:
Missing["NotFound"]
"NotFound"
*)
```

You didn't specify what to do in that case, so I'll leave the handling of those cases to whatever is best to your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you want to modify your answer, the handling should be to output the position of the last element of the list.

Comment: Upvote for `FirstPosition`. I always feel silly putting those two 1s in arguments to `Position` and wonder why levelspec isn't the last argument.

Comment: @space_voyager OK thanks for the clarification; I included that in an ad hoc function.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. To be honest, I find the syntax and output of `Position` rather confusing myself, so I often have to look up to get just right.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If your size function behaves something like this:

```
sizeFunc[x_] := {1, 1}
sizeFunc[d] := {3, 2, 1}
```

then `Select` can get you the first element matching your negative criterion. Like this:

```
Select[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, sizeFunc[#]!={1, 1} &, 1]
```

If you want to use `Position` to get the position of the element in the list (rather than the element itself), you have to supply a *pattern* rather than a *criterion*.

```
Position[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, x_ /; sizeFunc[x] != {1, 1}, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `Position[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, x_ /; sizeFunc[x] != {1, 1}, 1]]+1` did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[`FirstPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html) allows for a default value:

```
sizeFunc[a | b | d | e | f] = {1, 1};
sizeFunc[c] = {2, 3};

list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

FirstPosition[list, _?(sizeFunc[#] != {1, 1} &), {Length @ list}]
```

> ```
> {3}
> ```

```
sizeFunc[c] = {1, 1};

FirstPosition[list, _?(sizeFunc[#] != {1, 1} &), {Length @ list}]
```

> ```
> {6}
> ```

Without `FirstPosition` one might use:

```
Position[list, _?(sizeFunc[#] != {1, 1} &), 1, 1] /.
  {{p_List} :> p, {} :> {Length@list}}
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you for pointing that out. That makes for a nice terse one-liner. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the link correction!  I also added a method using `Position` that is reasonably clean.